# passing shared array in julia using @everywhere

Tags: parallel-processing, julia

I found this post - [Shared array usage in Julia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35751420/shared-array-usage-in-julia), which is clearly close but I still don't really understand what to do in my case.

I am trying to pass a shared array to a function I define, and call that function using @everywhere.  The following, which has no shared array, works:

```
@everywhere mat = rand(3,3)
@everywhere foo1(x::Array) = det(x)
```

Then this

```
@everywhere println(foo1(mat))
```

properly produces different results from each worker.  Now let me include a shared array:

```
test = SharedArray(Float64,10)
@everywhere foo2(x::Array,y::SharedArray) = det(x) + sum(y)
```

Then this

```
@everywhere println(foo2(mat,test))
```

fails on the workers.

```
ERROR: On worker 2:
UndefVarError: test not defined
```

etc.  I can get what I want like this:

```
  for w in procs()
         @spawnat w println(foo2(eval(:mat),test))
   end
```

This works - but is it optimal? Is there a way to make it work with @everywhere?

Comment: Did you try @everywhere test =...?

Comment: Can you post a reproducible example where you get performance problems from your use of `@spawn`?  I don't see anything wrong with the example at the end that you post using `@spawn`, nor could I reproduce performance problems with it.

Comment: In playing with the thing more, I've come to believe, @aireties, that the performance issues are something unrelated to the use or not of everywhere.  I think I mixed some other code differences when I made my comparisons.  So my apologies for the ill-posed post.  Not sure what the proper action to take is now - remove the post?

Comment: I don't think you need to remove the post, just edit it a bit.  The initial error that you report getting is one that I think other users may encounter, and the answer from @tholy is useful for that.  I would just remove the references in the post to the slowdowns and leave it about the error message.  I actually think it's a great initial question you asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it's tempting to use "named variables" on workers, it generally seems to work better if you access them via references. Schematically, you might do something like this:

```
mat = [@spawnat p rand(3,3) for p in workers()] # process 1 holds references to objects on workers
@sync for (i, p) in enumerate(workers())
    @spawnat p foo(mat[i], sharedarray)
end
```

Comment: In addition, using `@everywhere` to start processor intensive jobs is usually suboptimal.  You don't want your main controller processor doing heavy work, which is what the `@everywhere` macro can lead to without a lot of awkward code to avoid it.

Comment: This does seem like better form, @tholy.  However it doesn't seem to quite work for me.  If I do this, mat[i] is a remote reference, and remains one when passed  via spawnat.    So I will actually generate an error on the worker processes if the first argument of foo is supposed to be an Array (I tried it!).  I can fix it by replacing mat[i] with fetch(mat[i]).  But does this actually pull the value of mat[i] back to process 1 and then send it to process p?

Comment: I wasn't able to test that due to being on my phone. In your function you should be able to add a `fetch` to the function you're running.

Comment: @LeonBalents I don't think that spawn combined with fetch as you describe should do that.  Spawn means the command is run on the worker.  I haven't tried to explicitly test it though